# Ruby On Rails, and multi threading

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I came across that Ruby doesn't really have any performance benefit when you do multi threading. because of [GIL nature](https://medium.com/@adrianbooth/exploring-rubys-multi-threaded-weirdness-d5dc61883591).

***I see there is no point of using multi-threading in Rails app.
What is use case of multi-threading in Rails app?***

Comment: This is only true if the threads are attempting to do compute-heavy tasks. A typical webserver spends a lot of time waiting on IO (eg a database query to return) and threads still benefit in this case even when a language has a GIL.

Comment: Also note that GIL part of the MRI ruby implementation. Other variants such as jruby do not have a GIL.

Answer (score 0):

An IO (input/output) operation is one that is **not** operating on your CPU, such as, reading from a hard drive, an API call to a service, a database operation of some kind.

Anything that is IO heavy would benefit from multi-threading even with GIL. IO operations are blocking in ruby while they wait for the result, so it's only reasonable, while you are waiting for the result of the operation, to want to switch to another thread to do some work.